# How to fix the size of my TableLayoutPanel-pictures?

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, spaces, tablelayoutpanel

I have a problem with my TableLayoutPanel.
Every cell contains a picturebox, but when I would like to display my TableLayoutPanel (with the pictures), it appears some "spaces" between the pictures... How could I fix it ?

[Please have a look at this to see my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcNOs.jpg)

Here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _hauteurMap = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
    _largeurMap = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);

    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = _largeurMap;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = _hauteurMap;

    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < _hauteurMap; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < _largeurMap; j++)
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox
            {
                Size = new Size(20, 20),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
            };

            pb.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Sébastien/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/IsometricTileEngine_ITE/IsometricTileEngine_ITE/bin/Images/empty_tile.png");
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb, j, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `SizeMode = AutoSize` makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: I removed it, but i doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your pictures have margins. Try this :

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox
{
    Size = new Size(20, 20),
    Margin = new Padding(0)
};
```